# How to build OpenCV from deb files?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-18.04, deb

I have the following deb files after following the answers from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46122/how-can-i-create-a-deb-package-with-my-compiled-opencv-build) and [this.](https://github.com/wavelab/libwave/issues/106)

```
OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64-dev.deb
OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64-libs.deb
OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64-scripts.deb
OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64.tar.gz
OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64.tar.Z
```

I have generated them after turning on `CPACK_BINARY=ON`however I do not know the build order in order to successfully build OpenCV. How do I properly install them?

Answer (score 0):

You should also get a shell script, mine is called `OpenCV-unknown-aarch64.sh`, yours will probably be called `OpenCV-4.0.1-x86_64.sh`

Then to install I just go to the folder with the deb files and run `./OpenCV-unknown-aarch64.sh`